# Windows 10 network adapter MAC address change

Tags: windows-10, networking, mac-address

Trying to replace original MAC address of my network adapter with a custom one, but it behaves strangely:

1. Changed MAC address (tried many custom ones, such as `0123456789AB`) within adapter properties' *Nerwork Address* item in *Network Connections*, then performing an adapter disable & enable
2. When opening GUI box again, desired address is written there, but when performing `ipconfig /all` or `getmac -v`, the original adapter MAC is used there, same when checking the DHCP log on my home router. I tried restarting the computer (not needed normally), but still original MAC in console and router, but customized MAC in adapter GUI box.
3. I checked Registry for 'Network Address' key and customized MAc is there within:

   ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\000x
   ```

What could be wrong? Why does the console tool still display the original MAC address, and why is it still used on the router?

Comment: Can you list a few other examples that you've specifically tried? The one example you gave is not valid as a host MAC, so it's not surprising that Windows would refuse to use it.

Comment: How do you know the mac is 'invalid' (whatever this means)??

Comment: The first byte of `01:02:03...` is odd, which means it has the "group" bit set, which means it's a *multicast group* MAC address and is not valid for use as a single host MAC address. A valid host MAC would start with 00/02/04/06/... and so on, but never 01/03/05/etc. (Out of those, the 2nd bit also has meaning; MACs that start with 00/04/08/0c/... are "globally assigned" with an OUI, while 02/06/0a/... are "locally assigned", but that doesn't matter as much; both kinds are still valid.) In short: The 2nd digit has to be 0/2/4/6/8/a/c/e.

Comment: Do you have source of your "rules". I am searched internet long time, ane read many discussion about MAC address randomization, but no one ment such issue. No one ment the windows should validate MAC address more, than it is a 12 hex chars.

Comment: Yes, [IEEE 802 section 9.2](http://web.archive.org/web/20240218124453id_/https://www.ieee802.org/secmail/pdfocSP2xXA6d.pdf#page=31) defines what a "MAC address" is (see "I/G bit"), and [IEEE 802.3 section 3.2.3](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9844436) defines how Ethernet uses it ("In the Source Address field […] reserved and set to 0"). (Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Unicast_vs._multicast_(I/G_bit)), also [Android's MAC randomization](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-mac-randomization-behavior), and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

A network card has a **permanent MAC address**, which you can change by reprogramming or replacing a ROM chip on the network interface.
It's unchangeable for all practical purposes.

A network card has an **active MAC address**, which is initially the permanent one, and usually can be changed with operating-system software with administrative privileges.
This is usually only temporary until the next boot.

Your change in the adapter properties of the "Nerwork Address" item
or of the registry key will only take effect after the next reboot,
with no guarantee that it will really be taken into account during
the reboot. Try it to see if it will work and for how long.

A free utility you may use is
[Technitium MAC Address Changer](https://technitium.com/tmac/) :

> Technitium MAC Address Changer allows you to change (spoof) Media Access Control (MAC) Address of your Network Interface Card (NIC) **instantly**. It has a very simple user interface and provides ample information regarding each NIC in the machine. Every NIC has a MAC address hard coded in its circuit by the manufacturer. This hard coded MAC address is used by windows drivers to access Ethernet Network (LAN). This tool can set a new MAC address to your NIC, bypassing the original hard coded MAC address.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i need to change MAC address inside of my batch script, GUI tools are not suitable